# Python regex sub named captured

Tags: python, regex

I missing something very basic here.

I want to match all instances of, for instance, `throw 'some string'` or `throw "error here"`.

```
p = re.compile(b'throw ["|\'](?P<err>).*["|\']')
```

This seems to work fine for matching. But, for instance, I want to replace `throw 'some string'` with, for instance, `throw new Error('some string')`.

My attempt at this:

```
p.sub(rb"throw new Error('\g<err>')", b'throw \'foobar\'')
```

Always results in:

```
b"throw new Error('')"
```

I have found the match but replaced `err` with an empty string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This matches and captures the empty string, followed by zero or more characters which are not captured:

```
(?P<err>).*
```

You want to move the `.*` inside the parentheses:

```
(?P<err>.*)
```